# EOFException error when trying to read from file with RandomAcessFile

Tags: java, java-io, randomaccessfile

I have been searching for help with this question and I have found loads of stuff about RAF but nothing that answers my question as I just can't seem to find why this isn't working!

As I'm trying to learn about RAF to later build a database with it, I have created a simple class called data which consists of these two methods:

```
// Writing the desired String into the file
public void writeFile (String text) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("text.dat", "rw");
        raf.seek(raf.length());
        raf.writeUTF(text);
        raf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException when writing");
    }

}

// Reading from the file and returning as a single string
public String readFile () {
    String output = "";

    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("text.dat", "r");
        raf.seek(0);

        output = raf.readUTF();
        raf.close();

    } catch (EOFException ef) {

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException when reading");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;        

}
```

I am calling these methods from my main method in main class:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String input;

Data data = new Data();
System.out.print("Input text here: ");
input = in.nextLine();

data.writeFile(input);

System.out.println(data.readFile());
```

but the readFile method only returns an empty String. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: When posting questions about an exception, you MUST include the complete exception, formatted as code (indent everything 4 spaces using the `{}` button in the editor). Would you go to your doctor and expect him/her to diagnose you without discussing any symptoms besides "I don't feel well"?

Comment: Thank you, I have now edited my post. This is my first time posting and I am sorry to have made a bad impression from the get go.

Comment: You left out the exception itself.

Comment: Thank you, now there shouldn't be anything more left out, I have copied the whole consol printout when I run the program. I am sorry for missing these things, I am still a rookie obviously but I'm trying to better myself.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch `EOFException` separately and not treat it as an error. You can also get rid of the `while()` condition and change it to `true`. The `EOFException` you're getting just means you reached the end of the file.

You also forgot to close the file in both methods.

Comment: I have searched for rrue but I can't seem to find anything, what does it mean? How come not one single String manages to pass through and be saved in the returned output String? My brain is missing something crucial here.
Thank you for info about the EOFException!

Comment: Typo. `true`. I had fixed it. There is no data because you didn't close the file.

Comment: Thank you! The two methods now both close the file, but it will still not work. If I change the condition to true, the loop will never end.

Comment: It will end when you catch `EOFException`. That's what it's for. You should also initialize the string to "", not null.

Comment: Yes I am calling my write method and I can see in my text.dat-file that something is written into it when I run the program.

I now have an catch (EOFException) at the end of my read method. However, a problem arises that I cannot close the file after the while loop is done, as I get the error "unreachable statement", even though the loop does end just like you say.
Still, can't get it to work, the String output isn't saving anything. I changed the initializing to "".

Comment: It can't work if it doesn't compile. You should close the file in a `finally` block, and you need to open the file in read-only mode for reading. You may be recreating it with `"rw"`, I'm rusty on `RandomAccessFile` open modes.

Comment: My main post is now updated. I have made the read method even simpler to try and narrow down the problem. I now recreate the raf as "r" and not "rw" (I have tested both), and I try to save the information in the file to a single String variable: output. Output is still empty.

Comment: Still no close in the write method, and still no finally blocks, so no close in the read method if you get an exception.

Comment: I missed editing the write method, I do have a close in that and have now updated the main post again. About the finally blocks, if I put the close in a finally block, I get an error that it cannot find the raf-variable in that line. It seems I can only put the raf.close() command inside the try blocks.

Comment: That's just a variable scoping problem. You have to declare it outside the try block. Or else use try-with-resources. Are you still getting `EOFException`, or is it now working?

Comment: I decided to switch to buffered writer/reader instead since I have a deadline (school project) and have now gotten my functions to work properly. Thank you so much for your input though, I did learn from it!